# How to change the color of an array element in android?

Tags: android, arrays, colors

I just want to know , can we change the color of a particular array index? i have a following array-:

```
 String [] all={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
```

So , i want to print number 6 in red color and rest in black through ArrayAdapter.

How can i change the color of the array index? Please help me out !!!

Comment: text color or background color??

Comment: Yes , but how can i write the xml layout name in ArrayAdapter Syntax...   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, all);
 gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Umm, I think you need to create a custom `ArrayAdapter`. If you have a custom adapter already, post the code here. Otherwise, we cannot provide the whole code, though the answer to your question is: Yes, it is possible by overriding `getView()` on your custom adapter. See [this tutorial first](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

Comment: Ok ,, you need to add my snippet block of code info getView() fun like - getView(){for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        if(i<=6){
            Textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }else{
            Textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }}

Answer (score 1):

for text color create following xml in drawable folder:

**item_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="#777"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#000"/>
    <item android:color="#000"/>

</selector>
```

Now create a layout with textview only:

**item_layout.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/item_bg"
     />
```

in code:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_layout);
```

now if you want 6th item to have different text color call

```
mylistview.setChoiceMode(1);
mylistview.setItemChecked(6, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it simply...

```
for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        if(i<=6){
            Textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }else{
            Textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```

if you need any kind of help let me know!!